# auto switch back to low profile mode after seconds delay

Tags: android

quick question. I can dim the soft buttons by using the SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE flag. But when i click them , they stay in "normal profile" ever after. So what should i do to make them stay hidden again after seconds of idleness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen the changes in the `System UI` using  `View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener`. And then you can use a `Handler` to `postDelayed` Runnable to rehide again.

```
@Override public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO: hide system UI again. 
        }
    }, 100);
}
```